# how to produce change line character in rails view (.html.erb file)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried:

```
<%= "foo \n bar" %>
```

only getting "Foo bar". Rails seems to ignore the escape character. How can I produce the change line character since I get input from database and "\n" is part of the records to express changing line. (Do I have to write a textual parser by band in controllers? I think this way is too cumbersome...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [simple_format](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format)

```
<%= simple_format "foo \n bar" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace them with  html break line since <%= %> will just put the output as html. So,

```
<%= "foo \n bar".gsub("\n","<br />") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked code of [simple_html](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) function. It is actually a gsub call as follows:

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb, line 253
      def simple_format(text, html_options={}, options={})
        text = ''.html_safe if text.nil?
        start_tag = tag('p', html_options, true)
        text = sanitize(text) unless options[:sanitize] == false
        text.gsub!(/\r\n?/, "\n")                    # \r\n and \r -> \n
        text.gsub!(/\n\n+/, "</p>\n\n#{start_tag}")  # 2+ newline  -> paragraph
        text.gsub!(/([^\n]\n)(?=[^\n])/, '\1<br />') # 1 newline   -> br
        text.insert 0, start_tag
        text.html_safe.safe_concat("</p>")
      end
```

The reason previously it is not working is I need to add html_safe call. I remember I met this before. It is for rails 3 only. Therefore nkassis is not wrong.

In fact I can write the code as follows:

```
<%= "foo \n bar".gsub!(/([^\n]\n)(?=[^\n])/, '\1<br />').html_safe %>
```

Comment: simple_format is actually call `gsub` and wraps double spaced paragrafs with `p` tag.