# How to split string into paragraphs using first comma?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, split

I have string: `@address = "10 Madison Avenue, New York, NY - (212) 538-1884"`
What's the best way to split it like this?

```
<p>10 Madison Avenue,</p>
<p>New York, NY - (212) 538-1884</p>
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

String#split has a second argument, the maximum number of fields returned in the result array:
http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001165

`@address.split(",", 2)` will return an array with two strings, split at the first occurrence of ",".

the rest of it is simply building the string using interpolation or if you want to have it more generic, a combination of `Array#map` and `#join` for example

```
@address.split(",", 2).map {|split| "<p>#{split}</p>" }.join("\n")
```

Comment: I couldn't get my view to render correctly with this answer, but after adding simple_format before @address, it now returns the strings on separate lines.  It took me a bit of searching to find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328235/how-to-produce-change-line-character-in-rails-view-html-erb-file/5328286#5328286) so thought I'd share it. Cheers

Comment: Amazing. Never knew about this, but this will save me so much time!

Comment: Really great feature, today only came to know split will accept second parameter that will control no of items returned from the resulted array.

Answer (score 1):

```
break_at = @address.index(",") + 1
result = "<p>#{@address[0, break_at]}</p><p>#{@address[break_at..-1].strip}</p>"
```

Answer (score 1):

rather:

```
break_at = @address.index(", ")
result = "<p>#{@address[0, break_at+1]}</p><p>#{@address[break_at+1..-1]}</p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though `@address.split(",",2)` is correct. 
Running a benchmark for `split`, `partition` and a `regex` solution such as `@adress.match(/^([^,]+),\s*(.+)/)` showed that partition is a bit better than `split`.

On a 2,6 GHz Intel Core i5, 16 GB RAM computer and `100_000` runs:

       `user     system      total        real
partition  0.690000   0.000000   0.690000 (  0.697015)
regex  1.910000   0.000000   1.910000 (  1.908033)
split  0.780000   0.010000   0.790000 (  0.788240)`