# Can a string be broken into multiple paragraph elements while iterating in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on building a blog from scratch as I learn Rails, and I am hitting an issue: in my `Post` model, I have a form where the poster can add a title, a category tag, and the post entry. These are all added to the table as strings.

Here's where things get tricky. Like any blog post, the `entry` (the text of the post, in real terms) string will likely be multiple sentences long. For this reason, when I loop the `Entry` content in the view, it will show the post as a block of text, which I am doing like this:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="row">
            <h2><%= post.title %></h2>
            By <h7><%= post.author %></h7> at <h7><%= post.published_at %></h7>
            <p id="paragraph"><%= post.entry %></p>
    <% end %>
```

So technically, the content is being shown: it has a title, post info, and the entry, but this long block of text for `entry` looks pretty bad.

What I'd like to do is be able to split `<p><%= post.entry %></p>` into multiple paragraphs, say if I made up my own markdown and put `#` when submitting text to indicate a new paragraph.

I found [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594649/how-to-split-string-into-paragraphs-using-first-comma), which is almost perfect in splitting an array except, it requires you set a finite number of mini-strings (like there should be 3 strings sliced from the original).

Since some of these blog posts may end up having 2, 3, 4, and so on paragraphs, I need a solution that will lead to proper formatting.

I see two possible solutions, and this is my question:

1) Is there a better format for setting up the `Post` table than having one long string for the post content?

2) If not, what can I do to make the string more manageable from a style perspective when it actually renders in the view?

#### Possible Questions

*1. Why not just use a Gem?* This is fair. I wanted to try and make the project more or less from scratch for my own learning, as I am new. That's why I want to experiment with building the Post model and making an intuitive UI for submitting entries.

*2. Can I see what the migration file looks like?*

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :category
      t.string :title
      t.datetime :published_at
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string :author
      t.string :entry

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The definition of a paragraph is (roughly) "a few related sentences." The relation is semantic, rather than technical. That said, how do you define a paragraph in terms of your "proper formatting?" This distinction may seem pedantic, but it'll matter to your users, so it should matter to you.

Comment: normally you'll use something like markdown for the content and then you'll render it with something like https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet

Comment: @MarsAtomic, Yes, good point. When I say paragraph, I literally meant "into multiple <p> elements". My reasoning - and obviously there is more sophisticated styling - but this will break the text up when it renders. So if I want three blocks of text, rendering as three <p> elements would be a good start. Right now, it can only do it as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple place to start would be with Rails's [`simple_format`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) helper.

```
<%= simple_format post.entry %>
```

It formats a single line break as a `<br />` and 2 consecutive line breaks as a new paragraph.

So this input:

```
Hi
I'm on a

new paragraph
```

Would be formatted as such:

```
<p>
  Hi<br />
  I'm on a
</p>
<p>
  new paragraph
</p>
```

You could also consider integrating a Markdown parser later if you want to get more advanced.

Comment: Implemented this strategy and combined with other answer to use `text` instead of `string`, and it is working pretty well. Good suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I **highly** recommend that instead of a `string` you use the `text` as your datatype for `:entry`

```
t:text :entry
```

This is because most database types limit Strings to 255 characters, but Text can be as many as 4,294,967,296 characters.

More info here: [Difference between string and text in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354330/difference-between-string-and-text-in-rails)

Comment: Important distinction that I was previously not aware of. Made the change. Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure. I just found out this week while working on my own blog.